# How can i sort array: string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, sorting

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(mainpath, "animated*.gif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            Array.Sort(files);
            foreach (string str in files)
            {
                Console.Write(str + " ");
            }
```

files is string[]
files contain 51 indexs in each index a file.
For example in index 0 i see:

```
c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 102 Height = 102\animated102x102.gif
```

In index 1 i see:

```
"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 112 Height = 112\animated112x112.gif"
```

Index 2:

```
"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 12 Height = 12\animated12x12.gif"
```

And it should start that index 0 will be:

```
"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 502 Height = 502\animated502x502.gif"
```

Index 1:

```
"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 492 Height = 492\animated492x492.gif"
```

And the last index will be:

```
"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 2 Height = 2\animated2x2.gif"
```

That should be the order. But now it's all mess. 
So i tried to use Array.Sort but it's not working.

I also have this method that i used before for sorting:

```
private void Walkdirectoryfulldepth(string dirPath)
        {
            data = new List<string>();
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
            var sorted = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
            DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            string[] strDir = new string[subDirs.Count()];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in subDirs)
            {
                strDir[i] = item.FullName;
                i++;
            }
            NumericComparer nc = new NumericComparer();
            Array.Sort(strDir, nc);
            foreach (var item in strDir)
            {
                data.Add(Path.GetFileName(item));
            }
        }
```

But this method get string not string[] 
I want in the end that the variable files will keep be string[] but sorted.

How can i make another method like Walkdirectoryfulldepth but this time it will accept string[] ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort descending? How else would 5 come before 1?

Comment: The order is correct. If you want it in decreasing order, use .Reverse() after sorting.

Comment: what do you get if you data.sort() ?

Comment: Patrick yes. I want that the first index will hold the lower directory with 502x502 then 492x492 then in the end the directory with the file 2x2.

Comment: Is there even a question there?

Comment: N4TKD same as before. The reason i want to sort it is that i want to add the files to a trackBar and show the files on a pictureBox when moving the trackBar. Thats why i want that file animated 502x502 will be the first and animated 2x2 the last . If not and i will use it as it is now with the trakcBar i will see the files not in logical order. The files animated2x2 animated12x12 and so on in jumps of 10 untill animated502x502 so this should be the logic and the sorting.

Comment: Please see the link list.sort can be over written to do what ever you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
string[] strarr = new string[] { @"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 502 Height = 502\animated502x502.gif", @"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 492 Height = 492\animated492x492.gif", @"c:\temp\newimages\Changed_Resolution_By_10\SecondProcess_-Width = 2 Height = 2\animated2x2.gif" };
IEnumerable<string> strTest = strarr.OrderByDescending(p => p.Substring(p.IndexOf("x"), p.Length - p.IndexOf(".")));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more then just sorting on the entire `string` (where calling `Reverse()` is the best option), you can use something like this:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<string> asc = files.OrderBy(x => x);

IOrderedEnumerable<string> desc = files.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Inside the lambda expression, you can create sorting rules the way you want to, like stripping some text form the file name and sort on the remainder).